# How do I get this 100% height to fill just the remainder of the window?

Tags: html, css

So I have a left nav that can pop in and out. I put a little example without the popping in and out here: http://jsfiddle.net/crz4w89o/

But as you can see giving the left nav `height:100%` adds more room below the window and you can scroll down. But how do I make it so the height of the left nav just fills the window without adding more space?

HTML:

```
<div class="all">
   <div class="header">header</div>
   <div class="leftnav-container">
       <! -- will be animated to pop in and out -->
       <div class="flyout">
          left nav content
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.all {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height:40px;
}
.leftnav-container {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.flyout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 270px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

expected would be the content not overflowing outside the window. Maybe there is a better way to write this then using or relying on `height 100%`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of CSS `calc()` property to deduct a pixel amount from the height (vh units) of your nav container:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.all {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height:40px;
}
.leftnav-container {
  height: calc(100vh - 61px);
  position: relative;
}
.flyout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 270px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="leftnav-container">
    <! -- will be animated to pop in and out -->
    <div class="flyout">
      left nav content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Breakdown of the changes made:

- In `.leftnav-container` - we have set the height as `calc(100vh - 61px)`
- `100vh` refers to '100% of the viewport height'
- The 61px we deduct from this value is made up of:
- `.header` border width and height (41px)
- `.flyout` padding-top and padding-bottom values (20px)

Comment: Well put together answer. Calc is one solution. Flexbox is another.